# new Date(year,month,day) works differently in ie10 and ie11 Dates near DST change sometimes have a time value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Sometimes when you create new dates in IE10 and IE11 via new Date(year,month,day) the returned value contains a time. For instance

```
new Date(2010,10,7)
```

sometimes results in a Date value of: **Nov 6, 2010 23:00**

rather than the expected value of: **Nov 7, 2010 00:00**

Here is some example code that illustrates this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>    

    document.write(new Date(2013, 10, 3) + "<br>");
    document.write(new Date(2013, 2, 10) + "<br>");
    document.write(new Date(2012, 10, 3) + "<br>");
    document.write(new Date(2012, 2, 10) + "<br>");
    document.write(new Date(2012, 10, 7) + "<br>");
    document.write(new Date(2012, 2, 14) + "<br>");

    document.write("<br>Checking for new Date() with DST issues: <br>");

    for (var working = new Date(2014, 1, 1) ; working.getFullYear() > 2009;)
    {
        document.write(".");
        var newDt = new Date(working.valueOf());

        var dayOfMonth = newDt.getDate();
        dayOfMonth -= 1;
        var nextYear = newDt.getFullYear();
        var nextMonth = newDt.getMonth();

        var newDate = new Date(nextYear, nextMonth, dayOfMonth);


        if (newDate.getHours() > 0)
        {
            document.write("<br>" + newDate + "  from:" + nextYear + "," + nextMonth + "," + dayOfMonth + "<br>");


            dayOfMonth--;
            newDate = new Date(nextYear, nextMonth, dayOfMonth); //skip over this date
        }

        if (newDate.getDate() === 1)
        {
            document.write(".");
        }

        working = newDate;
    }
    document.write("<br>done.");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output from IE10 & IE11 will look like this:

```
Sun Nov 3 00:00:00 CDT 2013
Sun Mar 10 00:00:00 CST 2013
Sat Nov 3 00:00:00 CDT 2012
Sat Mar 10 00:00:00 CST 2012
Wed Nov 7 00:00:00 CST 2012
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 CDT 2012

Checking for new Date() with DST issues: 
............................................................................................
Sat Nov 2 23:00:00 CST 2013 from:2013,10,3
.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Sun Mar 10 01:00:00 CDT 2013 from:2013,2,10
..................................................................................................................................
Fri Nov 2 23:00:00 CST 2012 from:2012,10,3
.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Sat Mar 10 01:00:00 CDT 2012 from:2012,2,10
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Sat Nov 6 23:00:00 CST 2010 from:2010,10,7
.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Sun Mar 14 01:00:00 CDT 2010 from:2010,2,14
...........................................................................
done.
```

The same code executed in firefox, ie9 and chrome does not create dates with time values.
I am pretty sure this is a browser bug but I haven't seen it documented elsewhere.

Comment: As you can see by the test dates at the top of the code this issue only manifests itself sometimes. For example if you remove all of the test dates at the top except for 
document.write(new Date(2013, 10, 3) + "<br>");
Then the code searching for bad new Dates will not return the dates in 2013 that it normally finds.

Comment: No time to research the specifics right now, but I am pretty sure it is related to the IE10 changes with historic dates, described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/03/25/spring-forward-advancing-historical-date-and-time-calculations-on-the-web.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj863688(v=vs.85).aspx